# Hanging Cable Problem - Determine sag given known cable length and distance between points.

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

All examples for the hanging cable problems that I've seen involve something like calculating the unknown distance between poles for a cable of a known length and known sag.

I've been trying to figure out how to re-arrange the equations to determine an unknown sag from a known cable length and known distance apart.

For example, what is the sag for a cable 3m long between two points 2m apart.

This was one of the sources I've looked at [THE HANGING CABLE PROBLEM FOR PRACTICAL APPLICATIONS](http://euclid.trentu.ca/aejm/V4N1/Chatterjee.V4N1.pdf) as well as the Wikipedia entry for [Catenaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary). The first demonstrates how to re-write the width in terms of the sag and length.

This is for a personal project where I'm hanging Christmas lights where I've now ended up down a rabbit hole and out of my depth mathematically speaking.

Comment: So, by $2$m apart you mean the same height and 2m apart?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: $+1$ although problem started with sag but ended up making me know how to solve $\sinh(x)-kx =0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the equation $$a \sinh \left(\frac{x}{a}\right)=y$$ as
$$\frac{\sinh(t)}t=k \qquad \text{with}\qquad t=\frac{x}{a}\qquad \text{and}\qquad k=\frac{y}{x}$$

Using Taylor series
$$\frac{\sinh(t)}t=1+\frac{t^2}{6}+\frac{t^4}{120}+\frac{t^6}{5040}+O\left(t^8\right)$$
Use series reversion
$$t=u-\frac{u^3}{40}+\frac{107 u^5}{67200}+O\left(u^7\right)\qquad \text{with}\qquad u= \sqrt{6(k-1)}$$

For your case where $k=y=\frac 32$, $x=1$
$$t\sim \frac{21041 \sqrt{3}}{22400} \implies a=\frac 1 t = 0.614640$$

Comment: $h$ is the sag, the horizontal distance $H=2x$ and the total length $L=2y$. 

$$a \approx \frac{x}{t} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{6\left(\frac{y}{x}-1\right)}-\frac{\left(6\left(\frac{y}{x}-1\right)\right)^\frac{3}{2}}{40}+\frac{107\left(6\left(\frac{y}{x}-1\right)\right)^\frac{5}{2}}{67200}}=\frac{2800\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} x^3}{\sqrt{\frac{y-x}{x}} (6761 x^2 - 1482 x y + 321 y^2}=\frac{1400\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} H^3}{\sqrt{\frac{L-H}{H}} (6761 H^2 - 1482 H L + 321 L^2}$$
so using equation 13 from the linked article the sag $$h\approx a\cosh\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)-a=a\cosh\left(\frac{H}{2a}\right)-a$$

Answer (score 0):

The paper you linked has the answer; namely, $$a \sinh(\frac{x}{a}) = y$$ gives you a fixed point formula for $a$. In your case, $x = 1$, and $y = 1.5$, which, by WolframAlpha, has two solutions for $a$, so we take the positive one, which is $\approx 0.616$.

Now, plugging that into Equation 13, we get that $z \approx 1.01$. So your sag should be around a meter? Can you verify this with your Christmas lights?

Comment: Right, and I see as described on Wikipedia you've got to solve for $a$ numerically. I'm trying to determine if there's a way to write (reference diagram) $z$ in reference to just $x$ and $y$ similar to how the article shows $x$ in reference to $y$ and $z$:
$$
x=\frac{(y^2-z^2)\ln(\frac{2yz}{y^2-z^2}+\sqrt{\frac{4y^2x^2}{y^4-2y^2z^2+z^4}+1})}{2z}
$$
This comes from wanting to be able to put it into an excel formula as I could the formula above; if you do plug in $y=1.5$ and $z=1.01$ into yields $x = 0.995$, which matches the expected value of 1

![][https://i.imgur.com/fAmZ0MA.png]

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*} y(x)
&=c\cosh(\frac{x}{c})\\
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
ds = \sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}
&=\sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}dx\\
\end{align*}$$
$$\begin{align*}
S_0^{2/1}
&= \int_0^{1}\sqrt{1+{(\sinh{\frac{x}{c}}})^2}dx=\frac{3}{2}\\
&=\int_0^{1}|{\cosh{\frac{x}{c}}|dx}\\
&=[c\sinh{\frac{x}{c}}]_0^{1}\\
&\implies c = 0.6164729394\\
\end{align*}$$